# pandasが学べる書籍を教えてほしいです。

Tags: python, pandas

連投失礼します。
pandasが学べる書籍を教えてほしいです。

「pythonではじめるデータラングリング」でpandasを取り扱うものと思ってかったら触れられてもいませんでした。

#### やりたいこと

実はわたしはとりくみたい問題というのはありません。pandasはcsvモジュールやxlsxモジュールよりも高機能そうだから便利なのかもしれないと思っただけです。しかも単にドキュメントを読んでも意味がわからないことが多いので初心者向けに解説されている本がいいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「Pythonによるデータ分析入門 ―NumPy、pandasを使ったデータ処理」で詳しく解説されています。
pandas作者であるWes McKinney氏が著者です。

注意する点としては、原著は第二版が刊行されているため、邦訳本も第二版になるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。入門から入るほうがいいかもしれないですね。

Comment: pandasを専門で扱っているわけではないですが、「Pythonエンジニア ファーストブック」や、拙著で恐縮ですが「PythonユーザのためのJupyter［実践］入門」などはpandasの要点がまとまっていると思います。

チュートリアルとしては10 Minutes to pandasもよいかと。
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「pythonではじめるデータラングリング」という書籍が地雷だっため、書籍を買うのが怖くなり質問させていただきました。感覚をつかむのならばチュートリアルもいいかもしれないですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: データラングリングの整形というのは「csvファイルをおいかけながらコードもおいかけながら」、でかなりわかりにくくなにをやっているのか、感覚がつかめませんでした。自分のが頭が悪いだけだとは思いますが。pythonではじめるデータラングリングは初心者にとっては地雷です。

Comment: この本、僕はイライラして読んでいられなかったです。特にテストデータを、シードなしの乱数で生成した例が多く、手元で試しても当然同じ結果にならないし、乱数が入力なら出力もランダムなので、自分が正しいことをやっているのか分からないのです。第二版では改善されているかもしれませんが